# Quick way to make an automatically color-coded Google sheet for every day of the year?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

So if the day is January 1st, the cell will be one color. If it's January 2nd, it'll be another color, and so on for every day of the year. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

- you can try **color scale** in conditional formatting:

  [image]
- **note:** to hit exact midpoint, disable it, set minpoint and maxpoint and then enable midpoint